# CSS Border radius does not work in jQuery-word-export plugin

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to export a circular image using inline CSS, but when exported to a Word document, I am getting a huge rectangular image. Why? And how can I solve this? Is there perhaps another way to export it simply (to .docx or PDF or something)?

I am using the jQuery-word-export plug-in developed by markswindoll.

What I am trying is this: [Profile picture example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvJFL.png) 
What I am getting is this: [Exported example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6IWbh.png)

My code is:

```
<div  id="export-content">
    <!-- PROFILE PICTURE -->
    <div id="divProfielfoto" ng-controller="profielfotoCtrl">
        <img id="profielfoto" ng-src="{{profielfoto}}" alt="profielfoto" style="width: 125px;height:125px;margin-bottom: 20px; border-radius:50%; border: 7px solid orange;" />
    </div>
    <input style="display: none;" id="profileUpload" type="file" accept="image/*"/>
    <!-- PROFILE PICTURE END -->
</div>
<button class="word-export" onclick="export()">Export as .doc</button>
```

My code for exporting is as follows:

```
$(".word-export").click(function (event) {
        $("#export-content").wordExport("CV " + naam);
    });
```

Any other plug-ins/solutions are also welcome, if they are simple to use (I am a beginner at web app development)

Comment: I would guess that the export-library doesn't have code to support circular borders in Word? Probably not that much you can do about it, unfortunately, except rewriting the library, or add it as a request to the developer.

Comment: If it does not work, have you tried to use that border by background image for your #divProfielfoto div ?

Comment: nguyenhoai890 I tried that, but it does not work. Well, in the exported file it does work with the border (it shows), but not as a circle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin draws a canvas from all images in the HTML. The thing you have to do is replace this:

```
// Embed all images using Data URLs
        var images = Array();
        var img = markup.find('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
            // Calculate dimensions of output image
            var w = Math.min(img[i].width, options.maxWidth);
            var h = img[i].height * (w / img[i].width);
            // Create canvas for converting image to data URL
            var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
            canvas.width = w;
            canvas.height = h;
            // Draw image to canvas
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0, w, h);
            // Get data URL encoding of image
            var uri = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            $(img[i]).attr("src", img[i].src);
            img[i].width = w;
            img[i].height = h;
            // Save encoded image to array
            images[i] = {
                type: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(":") + 1, uri.indexOf(";")),
                encoding: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(";") + 1, uri.indexOf(",")),
                location: $(img[i]).attr("src"),
                data: uri.substring(uri.indexOf(",") + 1)
            };
        }
```

with this:

```
            // Draw image to canvas
            var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
            context.save();
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 62.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
            context.lineWidth = 10;
            context.clip();
            context.drawImage(img[i], 0, 0, w, h);
```

And it creates a circular image. Problem solved!